# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present always shows no matter what url I try to use

Tags: javascript, api, get, apache2, cors

I am trying to learn how to parse APIs using javascript and so I am trying to get some json through some get calls.

In my script I have

```
<script>

    function foo() {

            var request = window.superagent;

            var url = 'http://www.google.ca';

            request
            .get(url, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
            })
            .set('Accept', 'application/json');

    }

foo();

</script>
```

No matter what url I use, I always get this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.ca/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://server.com' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):22 Error: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
at s.crossDomainError (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/1.2.0/superagent.min.js:1:7899)
at XMLHttpRequest.s.end.D.onreadystatechange (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/1.2.0/superagent.min.js:1:8551)
```

I tried using various example get request urls like wikipedia, nba stats, google etc...that work fine when I enter the url into my browser but it does not work when I try to use javascript to download the data.

I am using a local apache2 server on my ubuntu laptop. I am also using the superagent library for javascript, but i also tried using jquery and ajax and it's the same error.

---

so apparently I need to use a url that uses cors. The thing is

http://savvastjortjoglou.com/nba-shot-sharts.html?utm_source=Python+Weekly+Newsletter&utm_campaign=5185ff0538-Python_Weekly_Issue_202_July_30_2015&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_9e26887fc5-5185ff0538-312727397

this tutorial just did a requests.get(url) which was the nba stats url and got his data. He did not get an error? How can I use a url that doesn't use cors to get data?

Comment: well you need to use a url that uses CORS... try `https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css`

Comment: @dandavis that did not give me an error but it was null so its progress I guess. Now how can I web scrape API data for websites like nba stats or other apis using this format? Do i need like a key / registration?

Comment: You should do your web scraping in a server script, not Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar ohhhhhhhh..that makes a lot of sense. If i use say php to scrape those websites, will I avoid this error?

Comment: Yes. You can also use a PHP proxy script to return the contents of the website to your Javascript, if you want to do the scraping on the client. See [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)

Comment: i would HIGHLY recommend doing scraping from JS, since so many sites use JS-injected content which PHP cannot see. you can ship the url data to JS from PHP, but you want JS's nice dom and array methods to iterate and filter the results, especially from non-api URLS.

Comment: @dandavis so I could use php to get the 'data' and then parse that data using javascript?

Comment: @albertkim: yes, exactly what i've found to be the easiest/more flexible. or, use tampermonkey to run scraping code from the domain in question, side-stepping CORS and PHP alltogether. you can then use iframes/a reusable popup to run the tampermonkey userscript on a list of URLs... i find it better to do the heavy lifting in JS so that i have jQuery/underscore, and so i can rapidly debug in devtools instead of `echo`+refresh

Comment: @dandavis alright thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

CORS is implemented on the browser end as well, to not allow javascript load malicious content from unknown sites. You should also try using the CORS plugin if you are still trying to scrap on the client side.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en